# Binding images dynamically but not all images are clickable in Angular

Tags: typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms

This is my typescript code where I bound multiple images dynamically in list items.

```
 for (let i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; ++i) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            console.log(this.imgs);
            reader.onload = (e: any) => {
                var src = e.target.result;
                $("#UiImage").append("<li style=\"float:left;margin: 10px 5px\" id=\"liimage" + i + "\" ><img src=\"" + src + "\" id=\"Upimage" + i + "\" (click)=\"ZoomImage()\" \height=\"100px\" \width=\"100px\" /></li> &nbsp;");
                this.imgs.push(src);
                this.src_pt = src;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[i]);
        }
```

When I click particular image for preview, that click event is not working.

Comment: You can't just append HTML with Angular expressions to the DOM with jQuery, and hope it will work. It won. ANgular compiles the templates at startup (or at build time, when using AOP). Stop using jQuery. Modify the model from your TypeScript code, and generate HTML with the angular templates.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. and Sir, I'm new to angular 2. i could not get the code for dynamic bindings of html tags in typescript.so only, i used jquery. Can you please provide the typescript code for the above mentioned code. and why we can't use jquery in typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Try this one and let me know whether its working or not? :

In HTML you do like this...

```
 <ul style="list-style-type: none; display: inline;" *ngFor="let row of rows">
                                <li style="float:left;margin: 10px 5px">
                                    <img src="{{row}}" width="100px" height="100px" (click)="ZoomImage($event,row)" /> &nbsp;
                                </li>
                            </ul>
```

And in typescript, you implement the loop concept as mentioned below!

```
  for (let i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; ++i) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            console.log(this.imgs);
            reader.onload = (e: any) => {
                var src = e.target.result;
                this.rows.push(src);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[i]);
        }
```